# How do Cloud-based services provide Qualified Electronic Signatures?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature

From what I know about QES, they come on smart cards and USB tokens and are password protected. When a site asks you for a client certificate, you need to have it plugged in and enter the password when prompted. Same when a desktop app tries signing a document.
Products like **Adobe Sign** say you don't need to hassle with "installing desktop software, downloading documents, and plugging in USB tokens or smart cards" and that you can create end-to-end signing processes and still be fully compliant.

Could someone ELI5 me how that would work?
Could these signatures be used for authenticating yourself on a website without any hardware?
How does it sign documents? How is that process as secure as when using hardware?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that many document signing solutions do not actually use crypto anywhere in the 'signing' process.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/how-can-cryptographic-signatures-be-somehow-linked-to-a-physical-signature for more info.

Comment: @mti2935 Hey, in this paragraph they explain how devices are equivalent to their cloud based digital signatures ([Adobe site](https://www.adobe.com/sign/digital-signatures.html#:~:text=How%20is%20Adobe%20Sign%E2%80%99s%20approach%20to%20digital%20signatures%20unique%3F)).
As far as I understand them, these signatures support PKI, not like the DocuSign example from your link.